# jquery selecting a child several layers deep

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following structure:

```
    <div class="container questions">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span>Do you have any pets?</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The rows in the container are generated and I need listeners for when the inputs change. What I have tried:

```
    $('.questions').children('div').children('div').children('input').change(function () {
            alert('answered');
            Question_Answered();

    });
```

Though this path of selectors does not seem to work, I have also tried several > child selectors. Trying to work with this stuff in jquery makes me feel dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work properly even when we dynamcially add inputs to div.questions

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.questions').on('change','input',function () {
    alert('answered');
    Question_Answered();
});

</script>
```

Comment: So I was making it way harder than I needed to...thank you!

Comment: Yeah, no problem, if you could please upvote and mark as solution, that would help a lot.